# va_arg prints random characters

Tags: c

My print function prints random characters with the va_arg function. I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Thank you for your help in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

int myprint(const char *str, ...) {
  va_list args;
  int counter = 0;
  va_start (args, str);
  while (*str) {
    if (*str == '&') {
      fputc(va_arg(args, int), stdout);
      counter++;
    } else {
      fputc(*str, stdout);
    }
    str++;
  }
  va_end(args);
  fputc('\0', stdout);
  return counter;
}

int main(void)
{
    myprint("Hello!\n");
    myprint("Number: &\n", 5);
    myprint("Number one: &, number two: &\n", 120, 1345);
    int ret = myprint("Three numbers: & & &\n", 12, 444, 5555);
    myprint("I just printed & integers\n", ret);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `fputc` would print integers?

Comment: So how I can convert the integers to text?

Comment: You need to use `fprintf(stdout, "%d", va_arg(args, int));`

Comment: Thanks! It worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

`fputc` takes an int, but prints an character which the `int` parameter value is [ASCII](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code. Simply cast `int` to `char`.

So using `fputc` for printing `int`'s wont work, you could write

```
fputc(va_arg(args, int) + '0', stdout);
```

but it's easier to simply use relevant function, as `printf()`, so everybody can easily read it

```
printf("%d", va_arg(args, int));
```

Hope you understand the problem now.